# How to create custom modal in reactjs app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I want to make custom confirmation modal whenever user wants to delete his own post. How to approach that to use as less as possible code? I was thinking about independent component with logic inside (user can send via props function on yes/no, etc) but the problem I can't figure out is how to mount this component when user click on a button? Do I need to use local state inside every component when I need to use modal? Something like:

 `showModal ? <Modal onYes={()=>{}} onNo={()=>{}} title='whatever you want' /> : ''`

Can I achieve that in other way? I hope I explained well.

Comment: use css absolute position and hide/show on the button click (use css display)

Comment: In the parent component that is to mount the modal yes you need to keep track of a state variable like you are doing above. Then your button will have an onClick that sets showModal to true which will show the modal. In the modal you can have a close button that will set showModal to false. This is a stand React way of doing things.

Comment: I recommend you [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-with-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HOC as well. Keep show/hide state inside HOC and then pass props/functions (with currying) from Parent component

**Small example** - https://codesandbox.io/s/withtoggle-hoc-8bd0r